# How do I extract keys from a dictionary that has {"key":[{"A":"1"},{"B":"2"}]?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python dictionary,

```
dict = {
    "A": [{
        "264": "0.1965"
    }, {
        "289": "0.1509"
    }, {
        "192": "0.1244"
    }]
}
```

I have a collection in mongoDB that has,

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d5a7f474c55b68a873f9602"),
    "A": [{
            "264": "0.5700"
        }, {
            "175": "0.321"
        }
    }

    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d5a7f474c55b68a873f9610"),
        "B": [{
                "152": "0.2826"
            }, {
                "012": "0.1234"
            }
        }
}
```

I want to see if the key "A" from dict is available in mongodb. If yes, I want to loop over the keys in the list i.e.

```
[{
    "264": "0.19652049960139123"
}, {
    "289": "0.1509138215380371"
}, {
    "192": "0.12447470015715734"
}]
}
```

and check if 264 is available in mongodb and update the key value else append.

Expected output in mongodb:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5d5a7f474c55b68a873f9602"),
"A": [{
        "264": "0.1965"
    }, {
        "175": "0.321"
    }, {
        "289": "0.1509"
    }, {
        "192": "0.1244"
    }
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d5a7f474c55b68a873f9610"),
    "B": [{
            "152": "0.2826"
        },{
            "012": "0.1234"
     }
    }
```

The value for key 264 is updated. Kindly help.

Comment: why {"012" : "0.1234"} from mongodb in key "B" removed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the python part and not the mongoDB, try:

```
for k,v in dict['A'].items(): #k is key, v is value
   process_entry(k, v) #do what you want with the database
```

Comment: I want to get this updated in mongodb using pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your mongodb collection is called your_collection

```
   data= your_collection.find_one({'A':{'$exists':1}})

   if data:
       #loop over the keys
       for item in data['A']:
           #check whether a certain key is available
           if 'some_key' not in item:
               do_something()# update
```